# Not Redirecting after validation pass

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

After my validation rules succeeds, it can read the function Comments::create.. but my problem is after the `Comments::create();`  it does not read the redirect anymore. It doesn't show any errors but it does not redirects

All of these code is enclosed in a Class named `WatchController` and a method named `store`

```
$rules = Validator::make(
    array( 'comment[comments]' => $data['comments'] ),
    array( 'comment[comments]' => 'required' )
);

//  My textbox  
<input type="text" name="comment[comments]" value="<?php echo $video->id ?>">
```

**Below is my code if Validation passes then it must redirect to videos/watch/1**

```
if( $rules->passes() )
{
    Comments::create($data);
    Redirect::to( '/videos/watch/1' )->with( '_comment', '<div class="alert alert-success">Successfully added comment.</div>');
}
```

I'll just show you my route in case you want to see it.

```
Route::post( '/watch/add_comment', [
    'uses'      => 'WatchController@store'
] );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return it.

```
return Redirect::to( '/videos/watch/1' )->with( '_comment', '<div class="alert alert-success">Successfully added comment.</div>');
```

Comment: oh my god.. i didn't notice.. problem solved.. thank you sir :)

Comment: No problem, glad it was that easy for you.